# Store an array of values to a key in JSON

Tags: json

AM new to JSON and was thinking if i will be able to store an array of values to one among the keys in my JSON object?

like {"a","e","i","o","u"} to a key called vowels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what about:

```
var chars = {vowels : ["a", "o", "u", "i", "e"]};
```

Now, you access the vowels via

```
chars.vowels
```

Note, that an array is defined using     [ ]    in JS.